# How to determine controller from @Html.Action in MVC .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Given you have:

```
ControllerA
ControllerB
```

And in the view for ControllerA you invoke:

```
@Html.Action("ControllerB", "Home");
```

In the 'Home' action in ControllerB, how can you determine what the originally invoked action & controller were?

I know I can determine the URL from the http context, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to use this to map back to the originally invoked controller and action.

Nb. The solution I'm looking for must be arbitrary depth. If ControllerB invokes Html.Action on ControllerC which invokes Html.Action on ControllerD, I need to be able to resolve that the original action was ControllerA::Home from ControllerD::Home.

Comment: Isn't that using the pattern wrong if you can map back strong associations through the View back to the Controller? Instead it might be better to track the state yourself by keeping information in a common place along the way.  This is just my first impression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ControllerContext.IsChildAction` property to determine if you are in a child action, then the `ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext` property contains all the information you need.  This has a `RouteData` property which can give you the controller and action name.